# non gui mode html reporting

Tags: html, jmeter, report

when I was trying to do non gui mode execution in Jmeter , to generate html report I was giving some empty folder path. each and every time when I did execution along with my html page some other csv files also coming . don't know what could be the reason this was happening all the time.. I was attaching a screen shot of that how it happening pls look into that and help me what to do..

thanks in advance..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwApb.png)

Comment: Have you read reports docs: https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html ? files of that type are mentioned there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have inside your test jmx file [Listeners](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners), as `View Results Tree` that you configure to save file, and it's created in the folder. you need to disable it when executing dashboard report .

Notice there's an open bug to [ignore listeners on non gui execution](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=62495) you can vote on.